# Flutter why is my widget condition check not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this in my `main.dart` (my very first app level page):

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialAppContainer());
}

class MaterialAppContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MaterialAppContainerState();
  }
}

class _MaterialAppContainerState extends State<MaterialAppContainer> {
  ...
  globalValues.showLoadingBar ? _buildLoadingBar() : Container()
  ...
}
```

But then, in one of my lower level components (`testpage.dart`) I want to control whether this loading bar is showing or not, so the idea is to put the loading bar on when a call starts, and stop it afterwards. So something like:

```
(doWhatever).then((_) {
  setState(() {
    globalValues.showLoadingBar = false;
    print(globalValues.showLoadingBar);
  });
});
```

The change gets printed correctly, but the loading bar doesn't go away. I tried adding a change on `testpage.dart` and that switches correctly:

```
globalValues.showLoadingBar ? Text('True') : Text('False')
```

Can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong, I am clearly missing something about the components/state control of flutter/dart.

Comment: `globalValues.showLoadingBar ? _buildLoadingBar() : Container()` is this inside build method? Also is `setState` called on the same component as `_MaterialAppContainerState`

Comment: Yes it is inside the build method. No it is not called on the same component as _MaterialAppContainer. I guess this is my problem then? But how do I call another component's build method (or how do I solve this problem in any way)

Comment: There are lots of way to solve it. One easy way is to use `InheritedWidget`, Another hacky way is to pass a callback function down to your low level child class. The callback function should call `setState` on parent class and you call that callback function from your child class.

Comment: If you give me an answer I can mark it as the correct answer, instead of just leaving a comment :) I would love to see an example of both if you can :)

Comment: I would love to help but I would need a bit more code to actually help you. You could add a bit more in the answer OR share a github gist OR contact me via [twitter](https://twitter.com/PublicFinal). I am a bit unclear on what code you have written so don't want to introduce something unnecessary to throw you off guard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best idea I could work out (the idea came from Shababb Karim's comment!) it so create an empty setState() function, and then reference that in a global place where you can use it. Here is an example:

Your home/main component:

```
  reloadMainPageState() {
    setState(() {
      // This just reloads this component, you leave it empty like this
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    globalValues.reloadMainPageState = reloadMainPageState;
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget _buildLoadingBar() {
    if (globalValues.boolShowLoadingAnimation == false) return Container();

    // Here you can return whatever component you want
    return Container(
      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4),
      child: Center(
        child: Loading(indicator: BallPulseIndicator(), size: 100.0),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Any other component where you want to affect the loading bar:

```
  globalValues.boolShowLoadingAnimation = true;
  globalValues.reloadMainPageState();

  // ...load your data (which takes a while)

  globalValues.boolShowLoadingAnimation = false;
  globalValues.reloadMainPageState();
```

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I have move loadingInProgress outside class to simulate globals. 
and use future.delayed to simulate a job execution

code snippet

```
Future _loadData() async {
    await new Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 3));
  }

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      loadingInProgress = true;
    });

    _loadData().then((_) {
      setState(() {
        loadingInProgress = false;
      });
    });
  }
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

bool loadingInProgress = false;

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  Future _loadData() async {
    await new Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 3));
  }

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      loadingInProgress = true;
    });

    _loadData().then((_) {
      setState(() {
        loadingInProgress = false;
      });
    });
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    if (loadingInProgress) {
      return new Center(
        child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    } else {
      return new Center(
        child: new Text('Data loaded'),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: _buildBody(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Everything is good, except that my `_incrementCounter` would be on another page, and that is my big problem. The `setState()` from the other page doesn't update my home page like you have it here